# What kind of rose bushes are these?

Tags: identification, roses

There are 4 bushes. I know one is a white rose and smells lovely. I couldn't tell you what kind or classification any of them are. If anyone can help me find out I would love it! Or maybe tell me a web address.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be best if you could post photos when the flowers are present, though even then, the chances of an accurate ID aren't high, but sometimes the flower will point to a particular type of rose, even if not the variety.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any basic tips for moving them besides the obvious?

Comment: Moving them? That's not mentioned in your question - the answer as to how  or even if its possible to move them is related to how long they've been in the ground

Comment: Tonyna, ask another question for moving these roses.  They are looking very happy at the moment.  Where do you live?  You also need to ask about how to prune these guys.  Do you have a winter?  That would be the only time to move these roses.  They are amazingly healthy...gotta know where you live, that soil looks...low in organic matter yet your roses are well adapted.  Are you sure you want to move them?  Shoot, I'd design AROUND these guys!!  Certainly need pictures of the flowers.  What is it you truly want to do with these plants?  Knowing their varieties will offer little help...